# layer list losses its shape in second activity after applying animation

Tags: android, user-interface, animation, android-custom-view

hi i am making an app where i'm basically i have two activities. In first activity i have one textview and imageview and in imageview i have set a layerlist as background and same goes for the second activity.
Now my problem is that when i apply shared element transition animation in first activity then both the textview and imageview are animated but layerlist in second activity losses its shape you can see the below images.

[image: Without animation first screen] 
and [image: Without animation second screen]

Now screens with animation

[image: With animation first screen]
[image: With animation second screen]

Now from the above images you easily see the difference when i use animation the image in second screen losses its shape i searched all over the internet but didnt get any proper solution so please if someone can help me out here.

my first activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_simple_one"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".newactivities.NewActivity"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        android:id="@+id/login_text"
        android:transitionName="login_text"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:layout_marginTop="215dp"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/simple_activity_a_imageView"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/login_page_curve"
        android:contentDescription="@string/lion"
        android:transitionName="@string/simple_activity_transition"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/simple_activity_a_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
        android:text="@string/lion" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My First Activity.java

```
public class NewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);
       // getWindow().setEnterTransition(null);
        //getWindow().setExitTransition(null);
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.simple_activity_a_imageView);
        final TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.login_text);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.simple_activity_a_btn);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(NewActivity.this, New2Activity.class);
                Pair[] pairs  = new Pair[2];
                pairs[0] = new Pair<View,String>(imageView,
                        ViewCompat.getTransitionName(imageView));
                pairs[1] = new Pair<View,String>(textView,ViewCompat.getTransitionName(textView));
                //pairs[2] = new Pair<View,String>(register_text,getResources().getString(R.string.register_text_transition));
                ActivityOptionsCompat optionsCompat = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation
                        (NewActivity.this,pairs);
                startActivity(intent,optionsCompat.toBundle());


            }
        });
    }

    public void gotoregister(View view) {
    }
}
```

my layerlist xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"/>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="-880dp"
        android:left="-280dp"
        android:right="-280dp"
        android:top="0dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/White" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and my second layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_simple_two"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".newactivities.New2Activity"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Or Login"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:transitionName="login_text"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/simple_activity_b_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/login_page_curve"
        android:contentDescription="lion"
        android:transitionName="@string/simple_activity_transition"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />



</LinearLayout>
```

adb output

```
  TASK com.mikescamell.sharedelementtransitions id=3129
  ACTIVITY com.mikescamell.sharedelementtransitions/.newactivities.New2Activity 2dfe0dbc pid=12919
    Local FragmentActivity 1fe8aa49 State:
      mCreated=truemResumed=true mStopped=false mReallyStopped=false
      mLoadersStarted=true
    FragmentManager misc state:
      mHost=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@29e1f212
      mContainer=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@29e1f212
      mCurState=5 mStateSaved=false mDestroyed=false
    View Hierarchy:
      com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{1f58ae7b V.ED.... ... 0,0-540,960}
        android.widget.LinearLayout{c0df498 V.E..... ... 0,0-540,888}
          android.view.ViewStub{2807a4f1 G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020370}
          android.widget.FrameLayout{22e8d8d6 V.E..... ... 0,38-540,888}
            android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout{1ab9b757 V.E..... ... 0,0-540,850 #7f080034 app:id/decor_content_parent}
              android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout{1b39c244 V.E..... ... 0,84-540,850 #1020002 android:id/content}
                android.widget.LinearLayout{1c29bb5f V.E..... ... 0,0-540,766 #7f080016 app:id/activity_simple_two}
                  android.widget.RelativeLayout{35609f2d V.E..... ... 0,0-540,61}
                    android.widget.LinearLayout{3471ac62 V.E..... ... 186,0-354,61}
                      android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{25b3b7b9 V.ED.... ... 0,0-168,61}
                  android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView{2195c7fe V.ED.... ... 0,181-540,766 #7f0800a9 app:id/simple_activity_b_image}
              android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer{3f55e9ac V.ED.... ... 0,0-540,84 #7f080003 app:id/action_bar_container}
                android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar{2cb871f3 V.E..... ... 0,0-540,84 #7f080001 app:id/action_bar}
                  android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{1232beb0 V.ED.... ... 24,21-394,62}
                  android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView{21d50129 V.E..... ... 540,0-540,84}
                android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContextView{1cc22cae G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f080009 app:id/action_context_bar}
        android.view.View{bcf1675 V.ED.... ... 0,0-540,38 #102002f android:id/statusBarBackground}
        android.view.View{3382660a V.ED.... ... 0,888-540,960 #1020030 android:id/navigationBarBackground}
```

Comment: @pskink sorry but i didnt get you.

Comment: @pskink please see i updated my question with the abd output.

Comment: @pskink what could be the problem here

Comment: if you call just `startActivity(intent)` (without any transitions) everything is OK?

Comment: yes without animation it is working fine

Comment: i really dont know what is going wrong here.

Comment: ok for testing replace `@drawable/login_page_curve` in both `android:src` with some static png image and see what happens

Comment: i did that i replaced it with other png images and it works fine

Comment: ok cannot you use `VectorDrawable` instead of that oval with magic numbers for `android:bottom`, `android:top` etc?

Comment: actually i have to use that shape as a custom background and i dont know how i can achieve that shape with vector drawable.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources

Comment: could there be any solution with the current files